# Inaccurate return using COUNT()

Tags: sql

I'm writing some SQL for our lab, and I have it all done except for the fact that I need to count the DISTINCT number of samples that get returned. Here is the working code without COUNT() incorporated. It ties together three tables. When I use a COUNT() function, I get inaccurate results. Do I need to incorporate a subquery in SELECT?

```
SELECT
  batchid,
  s_sampleid, 
  requestid, 
  u_labinstance, 
  sdiworkitem.workitemid,
  workitemdesc
FROM s_sample INNER JOIN (sdiworkitem INNER JOIN workitem ON sdiworkitem.workitemid = workitem.workitemid)
ON s_sample.s_sampleid = sdiworkitem.keyid1
GROUP BY
  s_sampleid, 
  batchid, 
  requestid, 
  u_labinstance, 
  sdiworkitem.workitemid,
  workitemdesc
```

**UPDATE (Working Query)**

```
SELECT
  batchid,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s_sampleid),
  s_sampleid, 
  requestid, 
  u_labinstance, 
  sdiworkitem.workitemid,
  workitemdesc
FROM s_sample INNER JOIN (sdiworkitem INNER JOIN workitem ON sdiworkitem.workitemid = workitem.workitemid)
ON s_sample.s_sampleid = sdiworkitem.keyid1
GROUP BY
  batchid, 
  requestid, 
  u_labinstance, 
  sdiworkitem.workitemid,
  workitemdesc
```

Comment: Your Group By is pretty useless if EVERY column from your select is grouped and there is no aggregate function. What exactly are you trying to count? Distinct rows in s_sample?

Comment: @cularis - he mentions this is the query without the `COUNT` function.  Also it's not useless, it's longer version of `DISTINCT` for those fields.

Comment: Take out the GROUP BY, count number of rows and whatever else, report back. With sample data and other things

Comment: @franklin - can you post your actual query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take out s_sampleid from the GROUP BY

```
GROUP BY
  batchid, 
  requestid, 
  u_labinstance, 
  sdiworkitem.workitemid,
  workitemdesc
```

Then, try *both* of these

```
COUNT(DISTINCT s_sampleid)
COUNT(s_sampleid)
```

The GROUP BY on s_sampleid will always give "1" so fix that, then see which of these COUNTs is correct.

Edit:

If you need the actual s_sampleid *and* the count, then you need the OVER clause and remove the GROUP BY

```
 COUNT(DISTINCT s_sampleid) OVER (PARTITION BY batchid, 
  requestid, 
  u_labinstance, 
  sdiworkitem.workitemid,
  workitemdesc)
```

This *should* work... otherwise it's a sub query

Otherwise, you should have mentioned you want the values *and* the count at the start

Comment: Yes, When I do a distinct count, it returns 1 when infact there could be upwards to 25 or 30 samples.

Comment: @franklin - remove the `DISTINCT` and remove the `sampleid` from your `GROUP BY`

Comment: @JNK: The messed up GROUP BY is the first issue, not the COUNT which could be correct either way

Comment: This works, but by doing this, it doesn't show the actual ID of each sample. The return count is accurate, though. Updated code in post.

Comment: @Franklin - I don't think you know what  you want.  If you want to `COUNT` the samples, you need to `GROUP` them.  If you want to know each individual ID, you don't `GROUP` but you also don't get a `COUNT`

Answer (score 0):

As the others mentioned, use `DISTINCT`.

Also, are you specifying a certain field or using `COUNT(*)`?  `COUNT(*)` will count all existing rows, `COUNT(field)` will ignore `NULL` values for the specified field.